# How do I print the data within this nested stdClass Object?

Tags: php, soap, stdclass

I am attempting to print values within this nested stdClass Object but I'm having trouble accessing them. How do I print, for example, the value of "originCity"?

```
stdClass Object (
    [FlightInfoResult] => stdClass Object (
        [next_offset] => 1 
        [flights] => stdClass Object (
            [ident] => SWA2558
            [aircrafttype] => B737
            [filed_ete] => 00:50:00
            [filed_time] => 1362879561
            [filed_departuretime] => 1362880080
            [filed_airspeed_kts] => 442
            [filed_airspeed_mach] => 
            [filed_altitude] => 410
            [route] => LBY MEI J31 VUZ
            [actualdeparturetime] => 1362880080
            [estimatedarrivaltime] => 1362882900
            [actualarrivaltime] => 1362882600
            [diverted] => [origin] => KMSY
            [destination] => KBHM
            [originName] => New Orleans Intl
            [originCity] => New Orleans, LA
            [destinationName] => Birmingham-Shuttlesworth Intl
            [destinationCity] => Birmingham, AL
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I am unsure of how to correctly format the question.

Comment: What have you tried? What troubles are you having? Does `echo $obj->FlightInfoResult->flights->originCity` not work?

Comment: I was attempting something similar to the solution but I wasn't able to see how the data was nested. The edit to my original post makes it very clear and I now understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
$object->FlightInfoResult->flights->originCity;
```

to access objects properties.

sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$var->FlightInfoResult->flights->originCity
```