# How do I echo the data within this nested stdClass Object?

Tags: php, nested, stdclass

I am new to OOP and having hard time trying to echo value of SMSMessageBody in code below:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetSentMessagesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SentMessage] => Array
                (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [ID] => 6567960
                        [LineNumber] => 30004554552584
                        [SMSMessageBody] => Lorem ipsum 
                        [MobileNo] => 9122588874
                        ....
```

I have seen these posts in stackoverflow:

- [How to print nested stdclass object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154331/how-to-print-nested-stdclass-object-array)
- [How do I print the data within this nested stdClass Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560742/how-do-i-print-the-data-within-this-nested-stdclass-object)

So I tried the following code:

```
echo    $client->GetSentMessagesResult->SentMessage[0]->SMSMessageBody;
```

But got this Notice:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\banks\newbank\sentsms.php on line 18

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, make sure you are trying to use the correct variable. Then, try to figure out *where* it starts to give you the error, is it at `$client->GetSentMessagesResult->SentMessage` or maybe at `$client->GetSentMessagesResult`?*

Comment: what is the output of echo `"<pre/>";print_r($client);`?

Comment: @Anant the output of echo "<pre/>";print_r($client); is 
SoapClient Object ( [_soap_version] => 1 [sdl] => Resource id #10 )

Comment: @FirstOne how can I test the level of error?

Comment: @AliKashi, my comment is already showing you that. You keep going up in the tree to find out if it stops giving you that error.

Comment: @FirstOne , I kept going up in tree one by one and the same  Notice persists in every one of them

Answer (score 0):

This is not an object, it's a string, so please check using `var_dump` funtion like as follows: `var_dump($client);`

It's showing a string then you can not access with this code:

```
echo $client->GetSentMessagesResult -> SentMessage[0] -> SMSMessageBody;
```